# Python-- cannot find pip.ini

Tags: python, pip

I'm not able to get PIP to install python-imaging-tk. I get the following error:

```
pip-could-not-find-any-downloads-that-satisfy-the-requirement
```

Some other users have posted about this before, and the problem seems to be that my pip.ini file is looking at http://pypi.python.org/simple/ rather than https://pypi.python.org/simple/ . All I need to do is edit the url in pip.ini, but I can't find it. I've tried:

```
C:\Users\jon\pip  ...and...  C:\Users\jon\AppData\Local\pip
```

Where should I look for the .ini file?

Answer (score 5):

the easiest way to locate the folder is by running the following command in the cmd.

`pip config -v list`

That will give you the paths that pip is searching in to find the config file.
It is possible that there is no `pip.ini` file in there. Then you have to create it.

Answer (score 2):

As https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html explains:

- On Unix the default configuration file is: $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf which respects the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable.
- On Mac OS X the configuration file is $HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf.
- On Windows the configuration file is %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini.

Looks like you're on Windows, so just

```
echo %AppData%
```

at a command prompt, and that should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The command prompt sends me to AppData\Roaming, but there's no Pip folder here.

Comment: @JonathanBrouwer, then you haven't properly installed `pip`.

Comment: I've installed several packages with pip already. Should I remove these before reinstalling pip?

Comment: @JonathanBrouwer, I'm not sure, because I don't understand how `pip` could work or where it saved data without a `pip` sub-directory in `%appdata%`, so I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: hmmm-- I run Python via Anaconda, would this make a difference in how the installations are done? If not, would it make sense to simply reinstall Python altogether?

Comment: @JonathanBrouwer it sure might, sorry but I'm not going the Anaconda install route just to try if it does!-)

Comment: @JonathanBrouwer  if you've installed anaconda, pip will work if you open the anaconda prompt.  Its in the start menu folder for anaconda.